# Grep ignore multiple lines

Tags: shell, grep

Is there a way with Grep to use the -v switch to ignore a line and the next number of lines after it. Its basically to filter exceptions from a log file i.e.

```
Valid log entry 1
Exception exceptionname
    at a.b.c
    at d.e.f
    ...
Valid log entry 2
```

grep it to produce :

```
Valid log entry 1
Valid log entry 2
```

I have tried `grep -v Exception -A 2`

but this doesn't work.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The -v doesn't invert the -A, just the match

Comment: With this simplistic example, it sure seems easier to grep for what you DO want instead of eliminating what you don't want: `grep Valid`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try awk:

```
awk -v nlines=2 '/^Exception/ {for (i=0; i<nlines; i++) {getline}; next} 1'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
sed -n '/^Exception/,+2!p' filename
```

Comment: [sed p command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-33) -- the  Note it is harder in sed to print line _before_ than lines after as you will need to use hold buffers per [sed_print_lines_above](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/sed-command-to-print-matching-lines-and-2-lines-above-673139/) Here is some info on [sed range addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Range-Addresses.html) @useless

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you might tell `grep` to also ignore any lines that contain leading whitespace:

```
grep -v 'Exception|^\s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on glenn jackman's, by piping some commands you can get the before/after behaivour:

```
awk -v nlines_after=5 '/EXCEPTION/ {for (i=0; i<nlines_after; i++) {getline};print "EXCEPTION" ;next} 1' filename.txt|\
tac|\
awk -v nlines_before=1 '/EXCEPTION/ {for (i=0; i<nlines_before; i++) {getline}; next} 1'|\
tac
```